# Getting Error on Calling Sevice From MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, testing, exception, mono, ubuntu-14.04

WebClient objCTSServiceClient = new WebClient();
objCTSServiceClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/json";
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
result = objCTSServiceClient.UploadString(URL + "/FunctionName, "POST", Data);Calling a Service like this and Getting Error : SendFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) from monoDevelop C#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your post as readably as possible, and provide more information. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for advice on writing questions. At the moment your question is hard to read and lacks a lot of important information - such as service you're calling, the stack trace, and whether you have any way of telling whether a request is reaching the service at all.

Comment: And now I see this is actually a duplicate of [your question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63338680/error-sendfailure-the-authentication-or-decryption-has-failed). Please *edit that question* instead of asking a new one.